# Finding $\lim \frac{3^n}{4^n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^n}{4^n}$$

I know the limit is zero because the denominator grows faster than the numerator in this case... although I still get infinity over infinity.

How do I "show" that the limit is zero? L'Hopital's rule is redundant in this case and doing $\lim e^{n\ln(3/4)}$ doesn't help.

Comment: A standard $\epsilon$-$N$ argument should suffice.

Comment: Hint:  Write the expression as $\left( \frac 34\right)^n$.  Note:  you should make it clear that you mean $\lim_{n\to \infty}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz What's that?

Comment: Well, $\frac{3^n}{4^n} = (\frac{3}{4})^n$ and $\frac{3}{4} < 1$...

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Why though?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire I am not sure why you mean by "why though". Why though what?

Comment: A quite similar question: [Is it possible to prove that the limit, as n goes to infinity, of the sequence $a_n = 3^n/7^n$ is $0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3135653). A more general question (one of many similar questions on MSE): [Prove that $|x|<1$ implies that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1385709).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Lhopital's rule is redundant.

Call the limit $L$, which exists because the sequence is bounded and decreasing.

The derivative of $b^x$ is $\ln bb^x$.

We get $L=\ln3/\ln4L\implies L=0$.

---

Also, $e^{n\ln(3/4)}\to0$, since $\ln(3/4)$ is
negative.

Answer (score 4):

One textbook proceeds like this.

(1) Bernoulli's inequality:
$$
(1+x)^n \ge 1+nx\qquad\text{when } x > 0, n \in \mathbb N
$$
Hint: induction.

(2) Use (1) to show
$$
t^n \to \infty\quad\text{as } n \to \infty, \text{when } t > 1
$$
Hint: use $1+x=t$.

(3) Use (2) to show
$$
s^n \to 0\quad\text{as } n \to \infty, \text{when } 0<s<1
$$
Hint: use $t=1/s$.

Comment: +1 too same reason

Answer (score 3):

The sequence $x_{n}=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n$ has recursive definition $x_0=1, x_{n+1}=\frac{3}{4}x_n.$

$\{x_n\}$ is decreasing and bounded below by zero. So it has a limit, $L.$

But $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1} = \frac{3}{4}\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n}=\frac{3}{4}L.$$

So $L=0.$

So you really only need that a decreasing sequence bound below has a limit, and simple properties of limits.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this:

$\dfrac{1}{(4/3)^n}=\dfrac{1}{(1+1/3)^n}<$

$\dfrac{1}{1+n/3}<\dfrac{1}{n/3} =3/n.$

Used: $(1+x)^n \gt 1+xn$, for $x>0$, $n$ positive integer

Comment: +1 Nice answer with Bernouilli's inequality.

Comment: LostinSpace.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note $3^n/4^n = (3/4)^n$ so let $\epsilon > 0$. Can you find $N$ such that $(3/4)^n < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$?

This would show that the positive sequence $(3/4)^n$ gets arbitrarily small, which is the definition of convergence to $0$.

Comment: No, how do I find it?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire $(3/4)^n < \epsilon \iff n > \frac{\ln \epsilon}{\ln (3/4)}$...

Comment: @gt6989b $\ln(3/4)<0$, so it flips the direction of the inequality: $$\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^n < \epsilon \Longrightarrow n > \dfrac{\ln \epsilon}{\ln 3 - \ln 4}$$

Comment: @InterstellarProbe +1, thanks, fixed mine, but yours is also formatted better, don't delete it...